# Importing new data to master database versus temporary database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am designing a MySQL database for a new project. I will be importing 50-60 MB of data on a daily basis.

There will be a main table with a primary key. Then there will be child tables with their own primary key and a foreign key pointing back to the main table.

New data has to be parsed from a giant text file and then some minor manipulations made prior to importing into the master database. The parsing and import operation may involve a significant amount of troubleshooting so I want to import new data into a temporary database and ensure its integrity before adding to the master.

For this reason, I thought initially to parse and import new data into a separate, temporary database each day. In this way, I would be able to inspect the data prior to adding to the master and at the same time I would have each day's data stored as a separate database should I ever need to rebuild the master later on from the individual temporary databases.

I am considering the use of primary keys / foreign keys with the InnoDB engine in order to maintain relational integrity across tables. This means I have to worry about auto-increment ids (primary key) not having any duplicates when I go to import the new data each day.

So, given this situation, what would be best?

1. Make a copy of the master and import directly into the copy of the master each day. Replace existing master with the new copy.
2. Import new data into a temporary database each day but change auto-increment start value of the primary keys to be greater than the maximum in the master. Would I then also change the auto-increment values for the primary keys for all tables (main table and its children)?
3. Import new data into a temporary database each day, not worrying about the primary key values. Find some other way to merge the temporary database with the master without collisions of the primary keys? If using this strategy, how can I update the primary key in the main table for the new data while making sure all the relationships with the child tables remain correct?

Comment: why can't you check the data as you import it?  Use a transaction and commit when everything looks good, or rollback if you want to abort.  Import in smaller chunks that you can verify so you don't have to abort the entire process if something doesn't check out.

Comment: IMO all three of the suggestions you listed are too complicated -- too many ways for them to break.

Comment: @Gavin, but are you not saying I should go with #1 with your first comment ("why can't you check the data as you import it")? One thing is that I have to import the new data and test it on a local environment before publishing online. So I have to do this offline with a copy of the database ... then I would just like to import the new data into the online master rather than uploading the master every day. With 50-60 MB of new data per day, the database will get quite large quickly ... then I'll have to upload this huge database to the server every day. That will be a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: I would suspect that with all three of these methods, you're going to run into conflicts.  If you did #1, what happens if the live database changes between the time you do your import, testing and then copy to the master?  I wouldn't go with any of the three ideas.  I would do your tests inside of a transaction as you import the data, then commit it when it's good.

Comment: Ah, I see. I forgot to mention the online version of the database is read only ... it cannot change between imports.

Comment: Then why not import your records into the full copy as in #1, then just move the new records from there to the master database each time?

Comment: I see. So I would make a copy of the master and import new records into the master. When everything is OK, I would just export the new records to a dump file and then use that dump file to import into the online master?

Comment: yes, that sounds like the simplest strategy to me =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is as complicated as you are making it?

Why not just do this:

1. Import raw data into temporary table (why does it have to be a separate database?)
2. Run your transformations/integrity checks on the temporary table.
3. When the data is good, insert it directly into the master table.
4. Use auto incrementing ids on the master table that are *not* dependent on your data being imported. That allows you to have a unique id *and* the original ids that might have existed in your import.
5. Add a field to your master table(s) that gives you a record of which import the records came from.
6. In addition to copying the data to your master table, make a log that ties back to the data you merged. Helps you back out the data if you find it's wrong/bad and gives you an audit trail.

In the end just set up a sandbox database, write a bunch of stored procedures and test the crap out of it. =)

Comment: I take your point that the new data could be imported into a temporary table ... although I will have maybe 12 or so tables so I would have to create temporary versions of all those tables. But what about maintaining the relationships between child tables and the parent? When I insert from the temporary parent table into the master parent table, then I also have to worry about matching the new primary key to the child tables ... how do I copy everything from the temporary tables (parent + children) to the master tables (parent + children) while maintaining the relational integrity?

Comment: To clarify ... you are importing one big table that has relationships inside of it? Or importing many files?

Comment: I would be importing about a dozen tables. One table is the parent table and the other tables are the child tables ... each child table has a foreign key that points back to the parent table.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I would import all of them to temporary tables. Should be easy to automate that. You could write a sproc that acts as a cursor to go through the master temp record - find all the children - and then copy them over to the live tables. Remember you can get the ID of a record that has been inserted and use that as the new master foreign key for the live child tables.

Comment: Having only been working with MySQL for a few months, I had to reread that paragraph about 5 times before I got it. =) I get the general gist, but would have no idea how to create such a sproc ... can you point me to a resource such as a tutorial that would put me on the right path? Thanks.

Comment: Check out this article: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/get-autoincrement-value-after-insert-query-in-mysql/ It tells you how to do an INSERT to a table with an auto incrementing ID and then get the newly generated ID after the insert. Set up some test tables and try that out so you get comfortable. I'd recommend reading about temporary tables too. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-temporary-tables.htm You can use those as intermediate tables that are not permanent. I don't think you'll need these, but you might also read about cursors. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: Thank you for the links. I'll review those materials ... much appreciated.